# How does multiple thread groups execute in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Lets say we have 2 thread groups, one has 10 threads, another one has 30 threads. I have unchecked "run thread group consecutively". In table results, we see response time of second thread group is more than first threadgroup users.

When threadgroups are arranged other way, it shows reverse. So, whichever is second thread group, its user showing response time more than what is there in first thread group.

Answer (score 1):

When you unchecked the "run thread group consecutively", then both the thread group runs in parallel. Now, based on the number of thread they will send the requests. In your scenario, 2nd thread group has created 30 threads and start sending the request. Now, based on,after how much time the response will come, it is listed in the view result. So, you thread group have more thread and  may be getting response faster then thread 1. But, thread 1 is also going to be listed in the view results as shown below;-

Option is unchecked, so parallel running:-
[image]
So,in short, if "run thread group consecutively" option is unchecked, thread groups will run in parallel else sequential.

Option is checked, so sequential running:-
[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: yes but look at Aggreggrate report listener, you will see First threadgroup executing and after its users are completed second row will get added for next thread group. Keep watching aggregrate report, you will see it.

Comment: For me, if the option is unchecked, Aggregate Report shows in parallel while the option is checked then it shown in sequence which is same as above. I am using jmeter version 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Only one explanation comes to my mind:

1. You're running your test in GUI mode
2. You're running it in GUI mode with Listeners enabled

If above assumptions are correct JMeter is simply lacking resources in order to kick off that many threads and given JMeter is not capable of sending requests fast enough you're getting "false negative" results as JMeter spends time in [GC](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) trying to free up some [Heap space](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space) in order to be able to operate.

So:

1. Make sure to [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. Disable all the [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners), they don't add any value, only consume valuable resources
3. Follow recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) in order to configure JMeter for maximum performance

Comment: I understand but I don't see request in listener when run in non gui mode. Added required lines in properties file too but doesn't work.